# is there a java api for getting the latitude and longitude from zip codes?

Tags: java, api, ip-address, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I am building an applet that requires an input of a location. however, because of the specific API that I'm using, that input must be Latitude and Longitude. the problem with this is that it would be inconvenient for users to figure out what their latitude and longitude is, and then type it in. however everybody knows their zip code. is there a Java API that can take a zip code, and return a latitude and longitude? (it can be from any random point inside the zip code, it accuracy doesn't really matter as long as that point is somewhere inside the zip code area) another thing that would work, is if it could get the location based on the ip address of the user. The last way that I was thinking of, was to look for ham radios in that zip code and get it's latitude and longitude. this was proposed to me by a friend that does alot of ham radio stuff, and he showed me [this](http://levinecentral.com/ham/grid_square.php). is this possible to do?

Comment: Zip codes of *which country?* You can always wrap for example Google's services for this purpose but one thing to keep in mind is that zip codes aren't unique, not by a long shot.

Comment: That would be too much data to store on the client side, basically storing longitude and latitude information for all zip codes. What you are looking for is geocoding http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/. You can send an ajax request with the zipcode and get back longitude and latitude.

Comment: Google "Java GIS" .. you should find plenty of links.

Comment: what if I were to use the ip address to get the location of the user, is there a way / api to do that?

Comment: Ip address? Hehe. No **reliable** way.

Comment: I found a different program that does the same thing, but the question is can it be done in java. It is at http://www.levinecentral.com/ham/grid_square.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be how you would do it in a regular application, it should be the same thing for applets.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  /** let's use the following zip code simply for the purpose of this 
      example (its the zip code for hollywood callifornia) */
  String zipCode = 91601
  String latitude = "0";
  String longitude = "0";
try {
                    /**
                      JavaCVS api is required in order to read this, it can
                      be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/
                     **/
        CsvReader products = new CsvReader("zips.csv");
                    /** a cvs containing all the zip codes and latitudes
                        and longitudes can be found at: 
                        http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/files/zips/zips.csv.zip/
                    **/
        products.readHeaders();
        int numOfHeaders = products.getHeaderCount();
        System.out.println("Number of headers" + numOfHeaders);
        try {
            while (products.readRecord())
            {

            String lookedupZip = products.get(products.getHeader(0));
            if (lookedupZip.equals(zipCode)) {
                latitude = products.get(products.getHeader(2));
                longitude = products.get(products.getHeader(3));
            }

            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

thanks to [@Ring Bearer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212211/ring-bearer) for the csv file link

Answer (score 4):

Don't think there is an API, but [the zip code database](http://zips.sourceforge.net/) can be used for creating one.

Comment: I used the database in your answer to write my answer, thanx. I didn't know that it was possible to have a simple csv file of all of them without taking up GBs of space. Is it really all of them (at least in the US)?

Comment: @Ephraim - zipcodes are constantly added to the system. How frequently does that sourceforge project get updated? We used it in our internal project a few years ago. Then it was up to date. If the SF project was abandoned, then you may have an out dated file.

Answer (score 1):

Google (afaik) [doesn't offer Zip Codes](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingRequests) in their geocoding responses. As I'm currently working on something like that, I had to decide something pretty similar and found a work around: districts. The geocoding response holds the name of the country, state & district, so your users can narrow it down. Chained selections are a nice addition.